# Windows Server 2012 R2 : Drive C: gets fragmented very quickly

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, scom, fragmentation, defragmentation

We are running Windows Server 2012 R2 with the Hyper-V role installed. I have discovered that the host's volume C: get's fragmented very quickly **(about 4% in only 1h).**

Our SCOM configuration triggers an alarm after hitting 25% fragmentation - and this happens, even when using the default scheduled defragmentation interval of once per week. The virtual disk files for the VM running on top are located on a different drive. The disk queue length for disk 0 and disk 1 is more or less 0.1. The most active processes with disk activity are:

- System
- Explorer.exe
- svchost.exe (netsvcs)
- HealthService.exe (SCOM Agent)
- mc2.exe (HP PowerProtector)
- sqlservr.exe (part of our backup solution)

But non of them is higher then 130 KB/sec...

**This is what the storage layout looks like:**

Disk 0 (RAID1 on 2x disks, strip-size 256 KiB / 256 KiB):

- Volume System Reserved
- Volume OS (C:)
- Volume SPOOL (E:)

Disk 1 (RAID10 on 8x disks, strip-size 256 KiB / 1 MiB):

- Volume DATASTORE (D:)

The RAID controller is a **Smart Array P420i**. Any advice and input on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much space is available on C?

Comment: 70 of 100 GB total are free

Comment: why do you even care about fragmentation numbers on a Hyper-V server's system disks? It is not that it would matter much performance-wise.

Comment: i don't our scom guys do

Comment: Set your defrag schedule to once a day. `Problem:` My car runs out of gas if I fill up the gas tank once a week. `Solution:` Then fill it up more often.